# the inner product between two vectors in the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

Let $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ be coordinates on $\mathbb{R^3}$ with the following parametrization: $$\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)=x_{1}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{i}+x_{2}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{j}+x_{3}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \hat{k}, \quad\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right) \in D$$ Let $$\vec{r}_{u_{1}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{1}}, \quad \vec{r}_{u_{2}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{2}}, \quad \vec{r}_{u_{3}}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u_{3}}$$ s.t $B=\left\{\vec{r}_{u_{1}}, \vec{r}_{u_{2}}, \vec{r}_{u_{3}}\right\}$ is a basis for a 3D vector space $T \mathbb{R}^{3}\left(\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\right)\right)$ s.t this vector space is a copy of $\mathbb{R^3}$ so it transfer the origin of $\mathbb{R^3}$ to the point $\vec{r}(u_1,u_2,u_3)$. Let $$\tilde{B}=\left\{\vec{f}_{u_{1}}, \vec{f}_{u_{2}}, \vec{f}_{u_{3}}\right\}$$ be the dual basis for $T\mathbb{R^3}$, Find $\tilde{B}$ and show that every $\vec{A},\vec{B} \in T\mathbb{R^3}$ can be written as $$\langle\vec{A}, \vec{B}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} g_{i j}\left\langle\vec{f}_{u_{i}}, \vec{A}\right\rangle\left\langle\vec{f}_{u_{j}}, \vec{B}\right\rangle$$
while $$g_{i j}=\left\langle\vec{r}_{u_{i}}, \vec{r}_{u_{j}}\right\rangle$$

I notice that the formula will work $\iff$ $r_{ui}\perp r_{uj}$
but why would the basis be orthogonal?

Comment: $T\Bbb{R}^3$ is called the tangent bundle of the manifold $\Bbb{R}^3$. This is not a vector space at all, it is a differentiable manifold. Given a point $p\in \Bbb{R}^3$, $T_p\Bbb{R}^3$ is a vector space called the tangent space of $\Bbb{R}^3$ at the point $p$.

Comment: so I still don't understand what does it say about a vector that is $\in$ $T\Bbb{R}^3$

Comment: Note that if $A=A^1r_1+A^2r_2+A^3r_3$ then for example 
$$\langle f^1,A\rangle=\langle f^1,A^1r_1+A^2r_2+A^3r_3\rangle$$
$$\qquad\quad=\langle f^1,A^1r_1+A^2r_2+A^3r_3\rangle$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=A^1\langle f^1,r_1\rangle+A^2\langle f^1,r_2\rangle+A^3\langle f^1,r_3\rangle$$
$$=A^1$$

Comment: True, I used that fact but I still have $r_{ui}\cdot r_{uj}$ for $i \neq j$

Comment: equal to delta-kronecker? not necessarily... this can be see in an explicit example

Comment: I mean that my problem is that while evaluate $\langle\vec{A}, \vec{B}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} g_{i j}\left\langle\vec{f}_{u_{i}}, \vec{A}\right\rangle\left\langle\vec{f}_{u_{j}}, \vec{B}\right\rangle$ I am getting term like $r_{u1} r_{u_2} A_1B_2$ wich should be zero in some way to the expression will indeed be equal to the inner product of $A$ and $B$

Comment: **it is** their inner product... why should it be zero for any $A,B$?

Comment: Lets write $A,B$ in term of basis $B$:
$A= A_1 r_{u1} + A_2 r_{u2} +A_3 r_{u3}$
$B= B_1 r_{u1} +B_2 r_{u2} + B_3 r_{u3}$
so $<A,B>= A_1 B_1 r^2_{u1} + A_2 B_2 r^2_{u2} + A_3 B_3 r^2_{u3}$

Comment: do you already dig in an explicit example?

Comment: I understand it is not necessarily. but I still not understand how this formula can be showed.

Comment: with a basis change that uses the normalized eigenvectors of the matrix $g_{ij}$

Comment: can you give an example for such that basis?

Comment: yes I could but let me explain that by arranging  the normalize eigenvectors of $G=[g_{ij}]$ in a matrix $R$ then $R^{\top}GR$ will diagonalize $G$ so the inner between $A,B$, in this new basis,  will be as you want.

Comment: but It needs to be done in any basis for $T\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: it is important to consider that if you want the new components of a vector $A$ under the basis change $R$ then $R^{-1}A$ has them... did you know this?

Comment: your initial basis is $\{r_1,r_2,r_3\}$

Comment: it is easy develop this train of ideas when $\vec r$ is an invertible linear transformation

Comment: @janmarqz Is this $G$ matrix has name? I understand now what you mean,it is a good idea but I am not sure how to write it formally

Comment: $G=[g_{ij}]$ is the metric tensor associated to the basis $r_{u_i}$. In a moment ahead I will write you an example

Answer (score 0):

This almost-answer delves one of the fine points in the comments.

First, by a process called diagonalization an inner product like
$$\langle A,B\rangle=A^{\top}GB=\sum_{i,j=1}^3 A^iB^jg_{ij},$$
where $g_{ij}=r_{u_i}\cdot r_{u_j}$,
one seek the eigenvectors of $G$.

Second, allocate them in a matrix $R$ and then
$R^{-1}GR$ and also $R^{\top}GR$ will be  a diagonal matrices.
So, by employing $R$ as a basis change then for
our inner product we'll have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle A,B\rangle&=&(RR^{-1}A)^{\top}G(RR^{-1}B)\\
&=&(R^{-1}A)^{\top}R^{\top}GR(R^{-1}B)\\
&=&(R^{-1}A)^{\top}D(R^{-1}B)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $D$ is diagonal.

Third, this last expression will be like
$$\langle A,B\rangle=\tilde A^1\tilde B^1d_{11}+\tilde A^2\tilde B^2d_{22}+\tilde A^3\tilde B^3d_{33},$$
where $\tilde A^i$ and $\tilde B^j$ are the components of $A,B$, respectively but in the basis of eigenvectors of $G$.

With this ideas maybe you were better suited to grasp for more.

Comment: with these clarifications,  perhaps you could construct examples, but I can do it if you ask for